# How to insert different selected checkbox values into database using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

```
<tr>
 <td>
   <asp:CheckBox ID="checkdoc" runat="server" Checked="false" />:Document
 </td>
 <td>
   <asp:CheckBox ID="checktwocheque" runat="server" Checked="false" />:Two Cheques
 </td>
 <td>
   <asp:CheckBox ID="checkIdprf" runat="server" Checked="false" />:ID Proof
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
   <asp:CheckBox ID="checkpancrd" runat="server" Checked="false" />:PAN Card
  </td>
  <td>
   <asp:CheckBox ID="checkAddrssprf" runat="server" Checked="false" />:Address Proof
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="4" align="center">
   <asp:Button ID="btnfarmrecordsave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClientClick="return Validations();"
    OnClick="btnfarmrecordsave_Click" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

iam not using checkboxlist control then how to write code  for inserting values into database using asp.net.Can anyBody helpme out.

Comment: Please explain your requirements.

Comment: i have 5 checkboxes if i selected any two or three checkboxes then i have to insert those values into database using asp.net

Comment: what is your insert query can you post it ?and what is your expected datatype in database ?

Comment: datatype is varchar and Normal insertion Procedure in sql server

Comment: So you are providing parameters ? Just convert your checkbox.checked value to string it will do .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better if your expected datatype is `Bit` rather than `varchar` ,However you can insert your values as ,

```
 string IdProof =Convert.ToString(checkIdprf.Checked);
```

Change your query use column name in insert query and use `ISNULL` to so that if a checkbox
 value is null it would be entered as `FALSE` rather than `NULL`.
 [HERE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)

```
 INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (COL1 ,COL2,....) values (COL1,ISNULL(IdProof,'FALSE'),COL3, etc.. )
```